# Using two alternative margin settings depending on $rootScope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wish to set within my HTML code a logic simplified as follows (this is the logic, not the desired code of course):

```
   if $rootScope.All_Tempo_Objects.Lang_Direction == "RTL"
      set left-margin = -20% 
   else
      set right-margin = -20%
```

Is there any possible syntax to express this as part of the style of a `<div>`?

Comment: `<div ng-style="{'margin-left': $rootScope.All_Tempo_Objects.Lang_Direction == "RTL" ? '-20%' : '', 'margin-right': $rootScope.All_Tempo_Objects.Lang_Direction == "RTL" ? '' : '-20%' }"></div>`

Comment: Thank you @AlonEitan for your prompt response. Very nice solution indeed!!!